# why the animation won't work but the print statement works?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

protocol Shakeable {}

extension Shakeable where Self: UIView {
    func shake() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = 0.5
        animation.repeatCount = 5
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.center.x - 4 , y: self.center.y))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.center.x + 4, y: self.center.y))
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
        print("Shaked!")
    }
}
```

then I have a model for a custom cell Where I implement this protocol. then I call the func in my controller

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TacoCell", for: indexPath) as? TacoCell {
            cell.shake()
        }
    }
```

I am new to coding so excuse my bad way of asking the question.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a picture. Pictures can't be referenced or searched.

Comment: This code looks fine.  Can you include the code that calls `shake()`?  It's possible, for example, that you're holding onto a cell reference too long and the cell that's shaking has been recycled.  Or UICollectionView's own animations could be stopping yours from appearing.

Comment: If you call this method from `viewDidLoad` it will not work. You can try call method from `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problematic line:

```
if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TacoCell", for: indexPath) as? TacoCell {
```

You are dequeuing a *new* cell, not grabbing the one already there.
You should be using `cellForItem(at:)` - this gets the instance of the cell which already exists.

e.g.

```
if let cell = cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TacoCell {
    cell.shake()
}
```

Comment: It did work thanks.
`if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TacoCell {
    cell.shake()
}`